# homotopy coherent G-action on tensor product of complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories

Let $G$ be a discrete group and $k$ a field. Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are complexes over $k$ with homotopy coherent actions of $G$ in the sense of Cordier (I've been reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07404.pdf as a reference). $C_1\otimes_k C_2$ should inherit a homotopy coherent $G$ action which induces the diagonal $G$-action on $$ H_*(C_1 \otimes_k C_2) \cong H_*(C_1)\otimes_k H_*(C_2). $$

How do I explicitly construct this homotopy coherent $G$-action on $C_1 \otimes_k C_2$? I'm interested in some explicit universal formulas (or a method for generating such formulas) in terms of the $G$-actions on $C_1,C_2.$ It is elementary to see how to do this "by hand" at the level of "2-simplices" (i.e. right down a homotopy between the composition of diagonal actions of $g,h$ and the diagonal action of $gh$). I could probably do something similar for "3-simplices," but I feel like this should be standard for people who know more homotopical algebra.